# How to mount Nvm EBS volumes of different size on desired mount point using shell

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

After adding volumes to an ec2 instance using ansible. How can I mount these devices by size to desired mount point using a shell script that I will pass to user_data

```
[ec2-user@xxx ~]$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:4    0  200G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:5    0    1M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p2 259:6    0  200G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:0    0   70G  0 disk
nvme2n1     259:1    0   70G  0 disk
nvme3n1     259:3    0   70G  0 disk
nvme4n1     259:2    0   20G  0 disk
```

This is what i wrote initially but realized the NAME and SIZE are not same always for nvm's

```
#!/bin/bash
VOLUMES=(nvme1n1 nvme2n1 nvme3n1 nvme4n1)
PATHS=(/abc/sfw /abc/hadoop /abc/log /kafka/data/sda)
for index in ${!VOLUMES[*]}; do
sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/"${VOLUMES[$index]}"
sudo mkdir -p "${PATHS[$index]}"
sudo mount /dev/"${VOLUMES[$index]}" "${PATHS[$index]}"
echo "Mounted ${VOLUMES[$index]} in ${PATHS[$index]}"
done
```

I am creating these using ansible and want the 20G to be mounted on /edw/logs but 20G randomly goes on any device. (nvme1n1 or nvme2n1 or nvme3n1 or nvme4n1)

How to write/modify my script?

Comment: What if more than one device is < 70GB?

Comment: Modified it to reflect more appropriately and what i wrote

Comment: Im not quite sure what your goal is, I don't see anything related to ***"validate both conditions at once"*** in your code. Maybe you need (at least) `size1=$(du -g /dev/"${VOLUMES[$index]}" ) ; size2=$(du -g "${PATHS[$index]}"); if (( $size1 > $size2 )) ; then echo "do something!" ; fi` ? Or at least that may give you some ideas. The `$` inside `(( ... ))` aren't strictly needed, but it might add to confusion for some maintaining your code later to leave them out. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I edited the question to make it more clear. And I will try your suggestion

Comment: I would have a "step" before the loop and force the 20GB to mount to `/edw/logs`. Remove that item from the loop lists, and then run the loop and allow the random assignment of the others. Good luck.